# first-of-type all over the page css3

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I get the first element from specific type.

```css
h1:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main Title</h1>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Another Title</h1>
  <div class="para">
    <h1>One More Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to set the "Main Title" `h1`, background red. The problem is that all the three `h1` `background:red;`

http://jsfiddle.net/EaEFa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only wanted the first **level** of h1 (rather than first of type within any element) you could use the child combinator

```css
body > h1 {
    background:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EaEFa/1/

Or you can combine them to get the first one only.

```css
body > h1:first-of-type {
    background:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EaEFa/2/

This does of course depend on the html structure, and what element the first `h1` is a child of.

Answer (score 3):

try this

CSS

```
.content h1{
background:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<h1>Main Title</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Another Title</h1>
        <div class="para">
            <h1>One More Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A nice non-CSS3 solution. Shows you don't have to be bleeding-edge about everything!

Comment: @Mr Lister: Selectors 3 has been a recommendation for almost 2 years now. It's not exactly bleeding edge.

Comment: @BoltClock I still think it's a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set the "Main Title" h1, background red. The problem is that all the three "h1" with background:red;

If you want to select only the first h1 element of all those that are on "top level", meaning direct children of body, then use

```
body > h1:first-of-type
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EaEFa/3/